# Lookup Java non-String keyed Java HashMap with string

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to have a `HashMap` keyed with a `CircuitId class`. The CircuitId class contains a String clci member and the class overrides the `hashCode()/equals()` by basically using the clci member's `hashCode()/equals()`.

I wanted to do this so that I can lookup the map using a simple string and do away with converting the string to a `CircuitId` object to lookup the map. But it doesn't work and I think because `HashMap` uses this evaluation form `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))` where key is the input key and k the key entry in the map, specifically the key.equals(k) part. I'm wondering why HashMap didn't do `k.equals(key)` instead?

(At least that way, i think what I'm trying to do would have worked.) But being that's not the case, is there a trick do this?

Comment: If you want to look up by string, why don't you just make that the key type? (And no, it wouldn't have worked if HashMap had used the alternative approach - unless your equals method will compare equal to an actual String, in which case it's broken in terms of symmetry...)

Comment: `key.equals(k)` would throw a `NullPointerException` if `key` is `null`, thus the `key==null ? k==null :` part is required.

Comment: show your code for CircuitID class..

Comment: for reason that constructing a CircuitId is expensive and to pay that price everytime just to lookup the map i find excessive. BTW i have this same question with LinkedList where i have to make the conversion when i want to look it up. If i have overridden the equals() with the check to handle if the key being passed is a string or an actual CircuitId object, i don't understand why it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: [In case you don't know what the `? :` syntax means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java).

Comment: My Wild guess is...Watch out the way you override equals() method in `CircuitID`. It should be `public boolean equals(Object ob)` instead of `public boolean equals(CircuitID)`

Comment: @Dukeling - that makes sense but surely they could have tested for nullness in the other case also, no?

Comment: @Vishal K - of course otherwise it would not be an override.

Answer (score 2):

> If i have overridden the equals() with the check to handle if the key being passed is a string or an actual CircuitId object, i don't understand why it wouldn't have worked.

Whether a container compares the circuit with the string, or the string with the circuit is implementation-specific, and it is not guaranteed to be the same in future releases of the JRE.

Generally, given two objects `a` and `b`, it is expected that `a.equals(b)` when `b.equals(a)` and vice-versa. That is called the *symmetric* property.

In the case of `CircuitId` and `String`, while you may override `CircuitId.equals()` and make `circuit.equals(id)` return `true`, `id.equals(circuit)` will always be `false` because you cannot override `String.equals()`.

You should use a `Map<String,CircuitId>` (and perhaps another `Map<CircuitId,SomethingElse>` in case you need to have `CircuitId` as the key in the other map.

Comment: Thanks for the response and to everyone who responded. My question has been answered. I'll probably stay away from the double map as the map could be huge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look up entries by `String`, you should be using a `HashMap<String, CircuitID>` or something like this.

If you want both, you might want to have two maps, or do two-level lookups:

```
CircuitId circ = knownCircuits.get(stringKey);
if (circ != null) {
     return otherMap.get(circ);
} else {
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CircuitId-keyed map, but override the `get()` method of the `HashMap` so it works with `String` objects too:

```
Map<CircuitId, CircuitLayout> map = new HashMap<CircuitId, CircuitLayout>() {
    @Override
    public CircuitLayout get(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof String)
            return super.get(new CircuitId((String)key));
        return super.get(key);
    }
}
```

You can similarly override `contains()` and any other methods you need.

The advantage of doing it this way is that you don't have to "corrupt" your classes by making them "equal" instances other *other* classes. And it puts any "ugliness" hidden in one (and the right) place.

Comment: what i really wanted was this form: Map<CircuitId, CircuitLayout> and be able to look it up with a string, thus, map.get("DHEC...").

Comment: FWIW I would use a String key, `if(key instanceof CircuitId) { key=((CircuitId)key).theStringId; }` so that from the POV of the map, the key to identifying a `CircuitId` is the string identifier, not a `CircuitId` object.

Comment: Why the down vote? What is "not useful" about this answer? I think it's a good solution, because it doesn't corrupt the classes and buries the funky code within the map impl, where it belongs

Comment: That being said, in certain controlled situations it is permissible to break symmetry of `equals` provided you are aware of the limitations and document them.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm new to this forum so I'm not sure if I inadvertently voted it down but in fact this is the answer I was looking for so I'll make up for it - up vote! Ngek I need some kind of reputation to vote so I probably wasn't the one who voted down.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey I agree with your opinion - since string is really an odd ball it's impossible to achieve symmetry with it. However I'm not sure if I follow your suggestion.

Comment: @Bohemian I still like your solution but upon closer inspection I still see the instantiation of the CircuitId class which I was trying hard to avoid. You see the construction of the CircuitId parses the string to its component parts and to do that just to look it up sounds expensive to me. I know I could really use just the string key but what do I do in the case of LinkedList<CircuitId>?

Comment: @mtkilbay: My thinking is that instead of constructing a CircuitId using the String passed to get, I would use a `Map<String,CircuitLayout>` whose `get` accepts a CircuitId and extracts the key string from it.  I'm guessing a little but it looks like every CircuitId has, or can easily have the string-form ID key.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey That is exactly what one should do, and that was my first answer (see the edit history for the original code if you want it). I only changed it because OP commented that the key must be a CircuitId.